# How would I change the color of the YoutubePlayerSupportFragment progressBar?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube Android Player API to play videos in an Android activity. This is my code for playing a video using a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` which is located in the `onCreate` method:

```
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youtubeFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeFragment);
    youtubeFragment.initialize(youtubeApiKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                            YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });
```

And this is the XML where the fragment is declared:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment" />
```

Currently whilst the video loads a teal colored circular progressBar is displayed. Is it possible to change the color of this progressBar and how would I go about doing this?

I want to change the color to the colorAccent of my current theme.

Thanks

Comment: Check policy, it's possible that you are not allowed to do that

Comment: Hi @TimCastelijns, I've checked through the API documentation for references to the progressBar but haven't been able to find anything. Is there anywhere else you would suggest looking? Thanks